# mysql - get total seconds for each hour of the day given start/end timestamps?

Tags: mysql

I have been thinking about this all afternoon and not sure if this is possible or not through only a query.  `test` has two timestamp columns (`start_time` and `end_time`).  I want to group by hour and add the seconds within that hour to a total.

So for instance, given a single row in `test` with these column values :

```
start_time = 1559865600 (06/07/2019 @ 12:00:00am (UTC))
end_time = 1559876710 (06/07/2019 @ 3:05:10am (UTC))
```

Result would be :

```
0 = 3600
1 = 3600
2 = 3600
3 = 310
4 = 0
...
23 = 0
```

There would be lots of rows of course.  The goal is to create results which show 'how active' each hour of the day is.

Editing this as someone voted to close it.  Think of the start and end timestamps as when an employee clocks in and clocks out.  You have x amount of employees.  The results would show the total amount of seconds all employees are clocked in for each hour of the day.  You could then see what hours of the day are the 'most active' hours in terms of employees working.  Hopefully that is clearer for some of you having a hard time understanding what I am looking to do.  That is the best example I could come up to get across what I am looking to do.

Comment: For whoever voted 'unclear'... what don't you understand from the description?  I gave what I have to work with and results I would like to get from them with an example.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry not an option in this case.